# Linking.openURL sample code doesn't work on certain Android phones

Tags: android, ios, react-native

While I was trying to use the following sample code from react native document for implementing opening browser function on Android, I found it wouldn't work on some models such as Pixel 4, Pixel 5 and Samsung S20 etc.

```
// https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking
const supported = await Linking.canOpenURL(url);

if (supported) {
  // Opening the link with some app, if the URL scheme is "http" the web link should be opened
  // by some browser in the mobile
  await Linking.openURL(url);
} else {
  Alert.alert(`Don't know how to open this URL: ${url}`);
}
```

But it worked when I made a modification:

```
Linking.openURL(url).catch(() => console.error(`Don't know how to open this URL: ${url}`));
```

I am not sure why the `supported` is always `false` in the first case on certain models. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

better solution for me was to use WebViev in separate browser screen, where you navigate the user:

```
props.navigation.navigate('BrowserScreen', {url: 'https://reactnative.dev/'}
```

browser screen:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Loading from '../../components/Loading';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import WebView from 'react-native-webview';

const BrowserScreen = (props) => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            {isLoading ?
                <Loading />
            : null}
            <WebView 
                source={{uri: props.route.params.url}} 
                onLoadEnd={() => { setIsLoading(false)}} 
                style={{flex: 1}} 
            />
        </View>    
    )
}

export default BrowserScreen;
```

Linking is cool to use for links that start with `mailto:`, `tel:`, `sms:` because it opens proper device's email, call or sms handler